# admob to listactivity confusing me

Tags: android, admob, listactivity

i am trying to set admob as a header to my listactivity 
in my listactivity i am using this to set the list:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.listview, values);
```

and (R.layout.listview) has only this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
style="@style/Font"
android:gravity="right" >
</TextView>
```

it works fine , then i added this to set admob :

```
adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "xxxxxxx");
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
layout.addView(adView);
adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

but it gave me an error

i am really confused!

i tried this to set the adView as a header :

```
lv.addHeaderView(adView, null, false);
```

but it doesn't help

please .... any help? or a step by step tutorial.

Comment: What does the layout of your activity that contains the list view look like?  Does it have a LinearLayout with id `mainLayout`?

Comment: no ... it has only the textview above

Answer (score 1):

You're experiencing the crash because `LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);` is trying to find a LinearLayout element in your xml file with an id of `mainLayout` and it doesn't exist.

Embedding ads within a ListView is a bit complicated.  You'll need to write your own ListAdapter to support ads.  You can pull heavily from this [AdMobListAdapter](http://code.google.com/p/google-mobile-dev/source/browse/adcatalog/src/com/google/ad/catalog/layouts/ListViewExampleListAdapter.java?repo=ad-catalog-android)  example which takes in your array adapter and embed ads every 10 list items.  Using the example link above, your calling code would look like [this](http://code.google.com/p/google-mobile-dev/source/browse/adcatalog/src/com/google/ad/catalog/layouts/ListViewExample.java?repo=ad-catalog-android) (posted below for reference):

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.listview, values);
AdMobListAdapter adMobAdapter = new AdMobListAdapter(this, arrayAdapter);
setListAdapter(adMobAdapter);
```

Comment: why can't i just use something like this : lv.addHeaderView(adView, null, false);

Comment: What object type is `lv`?  I don't see you defining it anywhere in your code above?